# How to assign a big stream bit into one column vector

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a large bit stream. (e.g. 10110001010101000.....001 size thousands or millions)

I want to assign this bit stream into a one column vector x.

```
    x = zeros(n,1);
```

I have tried to use some mod or rem operations, there will have some problems.

I guess it caused by the integer size.

I want to ask is there any good method to solve this problem?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: How is this bit stream represented?

Comment: Do you mean my raw data? I copied these bits from .txt file, the data is "10100101010101010100"(a binary bit stream), take 20 bits length for example.

Comment: Is it stored on a string?

Comment: Yes, actually I convert it from a HEX format, and output as binary format(using C program). And stored in a .txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, for example:

```
x = '10100101010101010100';
```

You could turn it into a logical column vector this way:

```
x = (x == '1')';
```

Comment: I found my mistakes on my code. And now it works with your method.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a simple subtraction trick with the ascii value of `0` -

```
x-'0'
```

Sample run -

```
>> x =

00101011001

>> x-'0'

ans =

     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     1
```

Then, transpose the matrix to get a column vector - `[x-'0']'`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider addressing the problem earlier in the processing, at load time. Each '0'/'1' character is stored as a byte, so load bytes (unsigned chars or `uchar`) which contain the character codes, then convert the character codes to the right 0/1 values:

```
fid = fopen('binchars.txt','r');
digits = fread(fid,'uchar') - 48
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Really thanks for your suggestion. Now I can read from .txt automatically. :)

Comment: @Liam Great! When you get the rep (15), please vote up the answer. :) Thanks!